# I am having trouble with my php variables

Tags: php

I keep getting "Undefined Index" for the following:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$email1 = "@";
$email_check = strpos($email,$email1);
$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
$pwd_conf = $_POST['pwd_conf'];
$uLength = strlen($username);
$pLength = strlen($pwd);
```

I have already tried if(isset()) but the error only changed to "Undefined Variable"

```
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
}
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
}
$email1 = "@";
$email_check = strpos($email, $email1);
if (isset($_POST['pwd'])) {
    $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
}
if (isset($_POST['pwd_conf'])) {
    $pwd_conf = $_POST['pwd_conf'];
}
$uLength = strlen($username);
$pLength = strlen($pwd);
```

Comment: Well.. which index is undefined?

Comment: You are on the right track, but you will get an undefined `$username` in the last line there.  Put the `$uLength = strlen($username)` inside the isset() block for `$_POST['username']`  Same for the `$pwd`  into the `$_POST['pwd']` block

Comment: Same goes for strlen($pwd)

Comment: maybe $_POST['username'] is not defined, check the content of your post vars with something like Live HTTP Headers.

Comment: I posted a which I find "Cleaner" way of organizing your code ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $uLength = strlen($username);
}
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $email1 = "@";
    $email_check = strpos($email,$email1);
}

if(isset($_POST['pwd'])) {
    $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
    $pLength = strlen($pwd);
}
if(isset($_POST['pwd_conf'])) {
    $pwd_conf = $_POST['pwd_conf'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't even think of compiling them.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is because one of your $_POST variables isn't coming through to the page.

In your first attempt, you get unidentified Index because the index part ['xxxx'] does not exist. In the second, your `if` statements are working and thus either `$username` or `$email` are never set. When you try to execute `$email_check = strpos($email,$email1);` $email does not exist (its possible this happens when you try to use `$username` or `$pwd`) and you get "Unidentified Variable".

There are a few ways to fix this, but I would start with checking your post data and see what is getting through to your page. There are probably multiple ways to do this, including one in php that I do not know about, but I like to use wireshark and inspect the post packets that are being sent; then debug from there.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would work:

```
$errors = array();

if (!isset($_POST['username']))
    $errors[] = 'Please enter a username';

if (!isset($_POST['email']))
    $errors[] = 'Please enter an e-mailaddress';

if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    $errors[] = 'Please enter a valid e-mailaddress';

if (!isset($_POST['pwd']))
    $errors[] = 'Please enter a password';

if (!isset($_POST['pwd_conf']))
    $errors[] = 'Please confirm your password';

if ($_POST['pwd'] != $_POST['pwd_conf'])
    $errors[] 'Passwords do not match';

if (count($errors) <= 0) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
    $pwdConfirmation = $_POST['pwd_conf'];

    // Other logic
} else {
    foreach ($errors as $error)
        echo $error;
}
```

Comment: there is not much sense in checking for isset() if no action is taken otherwise

Comment: I was just pointing out the way I code. There is sense in checking for each POST parameter if it's set, else you just shouldn't post it if you aren't going to use it. Also, notice my `// Other logic` comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are calling your code using GET method, and so $_POST variable is obviously empty.

You need to put all your handler code inside of this condition

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
...
}
```

while checking separate fields against isset() doesn't make too much sense

If you still get these errors - check your form then